# In android how to unstrike list item when checkbox of list item is clicked?

Tags: android, android-listview

How to unstrike the striked list item when a checkbox of a list item is clicked.I use Activity and not the listActivity.Any answer is helpful and appreciated.Thanks in advance. I use this code to strike off the list item when checkbox is clicked.

```
TextView tv =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewx);
tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

tv.setPaintFlags( tv.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));

Comment: I tried exactly the same code in the answer and it does not unstrike the text of the TextView. Am I missing something?